# Apache, mod_proxy_ajp and IE

Tags: ntlm, mod-proxy-ajp

I have an Apache 2.2 using mod_proxy_ajp as a reverse proxy for a Tomcat 6, running on RHEL5. On tomcat runs an application that does NTLM authentication.

Using Firefox, everything works ok, but IE7 says "cannot display the web page". Without Apache, IE7 works fine.

What is going on here? Unfortunately, I have very limited access rights and can't capture tcp traffic or anything like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make sure KeepAlive is ON

Comment: You nailed it. 
I found that one out some time ago but forgot to update this entry. One "correct answer" for you. :-)